# Overloading the subscript operator "[ ]" in the l-value and r-value cases

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, subscript-operator

I have overloaded [] operator in my class **Interval** to return **minutes** or **seconds**.

But I am not sure how to assign values to **minutes** or **second** using [] operator.

For example : I can use this statement 
`cout << a[1] << "min and " << a[0] << "sec" << endl;`

but I want to overload [] operator, so that I can even assign values to minutes or seconds using

```
a[1] = 5;
a[0] = 10;
```

**My code :**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Interval
{

public:

    long minutes;
    long seconds;

    Interval(long m, long s)
    {
        minutes = m + s / 60;
        seconds = s % 60;
    }

    void Print() const
    {
        cout << minutes << ':' << seconds << endl;
    }

    long operator[](int index) const
    {
        if(index == 0)
            return seconds;

        return minutes;
    }

};

int main(void)
{
    Interval a(5, 75);
    a.Print();
    cout << endl;

    cout << a[1] << "min and " << a[0] << "sec" << endl;
    cout << endl;

}
```

I know I have to declare member variables as private, but I have declared here as public just for my convenience.

Comment: that seems like a terrible example of operator overloading for the sake of it. Do you have some obscure requirement that forces you to do this? Otherwise it's just code obfuscation.

Comment: @jalf I know it's a terrible example, but I wanted to overload [] operator in generic class for Object Array.

Comment: @jalf: why http://cpp.sh/4fiz works without any compiler error ? Shouldn't compiler throw an error ? It gives nothing as an output. What is exactly happening in this program.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Return a reference to the member in question, instead of its value:

```
long &operator[](int index)
{
    if (index == 0)
        return seconds;
    else
        return minutes;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Change the function signature by removing the `const` and returning a reference:

```
long& operator[](int index)
```

Now you will be able to write statements like:

```
a[0] = 12;
```

Comment: Don't forget a const overload of op[].

Comment: That is, don't remove the existing one. *Add* this one.

Answer (score 6):

Overloading op[] to use hardcoded "index" values doesn't make sense here, and you actually already have the solution in your class definition:

```
cout << a.minutes << "min and " << a.seconds << "sec" << endl;
```

You can turn those into methods instead of public data members, that's inconsequential for not overloading op[].  However, since you want write access as well, the only advantage a method would have is validation (e.g. checking 0 <= seconds < 60).

```
struct Interval {
  int minutes() const { return _minutes; }
  void minutes(int n) { _minutes = n; }  // allows negative values, etc.

  int seconds() const { return _seconds; }
  void seconds(int n) {
    if (0 <= n and n < 60) {
      _seconds = n;
    }
    else {
      throw std::logic_error("invalid seconds value");
    }
  }

  // rest of class definition much like you have it

private:
  int _minutes, _seconds;
};

// ...
cout << a.minutes() << "min and " << a.seconds() << "sec" << endl;
```

Comment: I know it does not make any sense, but still what should I do If I want to assign values using [] operator.

Comment: @Searock: Another answer covers it, but I won't recommend it as a solution for this problem.

Comment: @Roger Pate +1 I know this is a very big stupid example but it's just to clear my doubt, my ma'am told me that overloading [] operator for assigning is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

return by reference to be able to assign values and use them on the LHS of the assignment operator.

Comment: I am a beginner in c++, so can you please give me an example?

Comment: @Searock sorry i was about to add the example. Just noticied Vijay already added the snippet. Please refer that. In general in C++ if you want to be able to use value returned by your overriden operator function on LHS of assignment then you should be returning by reference in your overriden operator function.

Answer (score 3):

converting the method to as given below should do it:

```
long& operator[](int index)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your array index member operator should be provided as

```
long& operator[](int index);                    // for non const object expressions

long const& operator[](int index) const;        // for const object expressions
```

Answer (score 1):

In-order to avoid confusion in the case of overloading the sub-script operator, it is recommended to use the `const` and `non-const` version of the sub-script operator.

```
long& operator[](int index);  // non-const function returning reference

long const& operator[](int index) const;// const function returning const reference
```

With `A[1] = 5`, you are trying to modify the object at `index 1`. So the non-const version of the sub-script operator will be invoked automatically.

With `cout << A[1]`, you are not modifying the object at `index 1`. So the const version of the sub-script operator will be invoked automatically.