# C++: Access via overloaded array subscript operator in 2D array

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

For the following function that represents a matrix

```
class m // matrix
{
    private:

        double **matrix;
        int nrows, ncols;


        class p
        {
            private:
                double *arr;

            public:
                p (double *a)
                    :   arr (a)
                {
                }

                double &operator[] (int c)
                {
                    return arr[c];
                }
        };


    public:

        m (int nrows, int ncols)
        {
            this->matrix = new double *[nrows];
            for (int i = 0; i < nrows; ++i)
            {
                this->matrix[i] = new double [ncols];
            }
            this->nrows = nrows;
            this->ncols = ncols;
        }

        ~m()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < this->nrows; ++i)
            {
                delete [] this->matrix[i];
            }
            delete this->matrix;
        }

        void assign (int r, int c, double v)
        {
            this->matrix[r][c] = v;
        }


        p operator[] (int r)
        {
            return p (this->matrix[r]);
        }
};
```

operator works for element access but does not work with element change. How can I add the functionality of `assign()` function to the operator?

Comment: Not yet another jagged edge matrix. Use a contiguous block of memory, pretty please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overloading the subscript operator "\[ \]" in the l-value and r-value cases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854419/overloading-the-subscript-operator-in-the-l-value-and-r-value-cases)

Comment: How doesn't it work? [This works fine](http://ideone.com/jdvl6G).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redefine your first accessor as

`const p& operator[] (int r) const`

and the one for setting as

`p& operator[] (int r)`

Then ensure that a value copy is not taken in either case. Returning a reference allows you to change the element value via the calling function.

Comment: how to "ensure that a value copy is not taken in either case"? if i get it right, p that is created is destroyed after function call

Comment: That's why you can't repeatedly create `p`. It always needs to be one extracted from the matrix itself.

Answer (score 1):

Your `p` class is private and you won't be able to call `operator []` on it.

Make p accessible, and in both `operator []` implementations you should return by reference, not by value. This will allow you to modify original data, not the copy's.